# Flutter: Why is the import for table_calendar not importing the event class?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, table-calendar

I have a task widget that I want to convert to a Event widget to place on a TableCalender. However when I try to create a toEvent function I am unable due to the package not importing the Event class. Why is Event not imported?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';

class Task {
  late bool isComplete;
  String name;
  DateTime dueDate;
  int priority;

  Task({
    required this.isComplete,
    required this.name,
    required this.dueDate,
    required this.priority,
  });

  Event toEvent() {
    return Event(
      date: dueDate,
      title: name,
      icon: null,
      dot: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        height: 5.0,
        width: 5.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Please share the error you are getting.

Comment: That package is from an unverified publisher and if you look through the source code there is no Event object and there is no Event Object in material.dart. This looks like bum documentation.

Comment: Thats strange as according to this flutter gems its the most popular calendar by far. https://fluttergems.dev/calendar/

Comment: I've tried to work with it and as returnVoid said the documentation is outdated. I'm attempting to work my way through it but its rough as it seems as some features have changed entirely such as the eventLoader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table_calendar documentation is outdated and there is no longer the and event Class or and eventLoader.